# Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller - Not sure how to fix

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

So I get an error saying that the supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller. What happens is my game works first time around in that clicking the `'Play'` button calls the `startGame` function and removes the menu so that the game is shown, but then at the end of the game when the `playAgainBtn` is clicked, instead of simply playing the game again / restarting the game, I get this error:

`ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()`

It specifically points to this line:

`menuLayer.removeChild(mainMenu);`

Here is the code:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.system.LoaderContext;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.Socket;
    import caurina.transitions.Tweener;
    import flash.text.Font;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public static var backgroundLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
    public static var gameLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
    public static var interfaceLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
    public static var endGameLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
    public static var menuLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
    public static var gameOverLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
    public static var howToLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
    public static var scoresLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
    public static var aboutLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;

    public var mainMenu:menuMain = new menuMain;
    public var gameEnd:endGame = new endGame;
    public var howtoPlay:howToPlay = new howToPlay;
    public var gameAbout:aboutGame = new aboutGame;
    public var intro:IntroSound = new IntroSound();
    public var soundControl:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

    public var gameTime:int;
    public var levelDuration:int;

    public var crosshair:crosshair_mc;
    static var score:Number;

    var enemyShipTimer:Timer;
    var enemyShipTimerMed:Timer;
    var enemyShipTimerSmall:Timer;

    static var scoreHeader:TextField = new TextField();
    static var scoreText:TextField = new TextField();
    static var timeHeader:TextField = new TextField();
    static var timeText:TextField = new TextField();

    static var scoreFormat = new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20, 0xFFFFFF);
    public var gameOverscoreFormat = new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 32, 0xFFFFFF);

   public function Main()
   {
        addChild(gameLayer);
        addChild(backgroundLayer);
        addChild(interfaceLayer);
        addChild(menuLayer);

        menuLayer.addChild(mainMenu);
        interfaceLayer.addChild(howtoPlay);
        interfaceLayer.addChild(gameEnd);
        interfaceLayer.addChild(gameAbout);
        soundControl = intro.play(0, 100);
        addMenuListeners();
   }

   public function menuReturn(e:Event)
   {

        addChild(gameLayer);
        addChild(backgroundLayer);
        addChild(interfaceLayer);
        addChild(menuLayer);

        menuLayer.addChild(mainMenu);
        interfaceLayer.addChild(howtoPlay);
        interfaceLayer.addChild(gameEnd);
        interfaceLayer.addChild(gameAbout);
   }

   public function showAbout(e:Event)
   {
      menuLayer.removeChild(mainMenu);
      interfaceLayer.addChild(gameAbout);
   }

   public function startGame(e:Event)
   {
        removeMenuListeners();
        soundControl.stop();
        interfaceLayer.removeChild(howtoPlay);
        interfaceLayer.removeChild(gameAbout);
        interfaceLayer.removeChild(gameEnd);
        menuLayer.removeChild(mainMenu);

        levelDuration = 30;
        gameTime = levelDuration;
        var gameTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,levelDuration);
        gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime);
        gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timeExpired)
        gameTimer.start();

        scoreHeader = new TextField();
        scoreHeader.text = String("Score: ");
        interfaceLayer.addChild(scoreHeader);
        scoreHeader.x = 5;
        scoreHeader.selectable = false;
        scoreHeader.embedFonts = true;
        scoreHeader.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;

        scoreText = new TextField();
        scoreText.text = String("0");
        interfaceLayer.addChild(scoreText);
        scoreText.x = 75;
        scoreText.y = 0;
        scoreText.selectable = false;
        scoreText.embedFonts = true;
        scoreText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;

        timeHeader = new TextField();
        timeHeader.text = String("Time: ");
        interfaceLayer.addChild(timeHeader);
        timeHeader.x = 500;
        timeHeader.y = 0;
        timeHeader.selectable = false;
        timeHeader.embedFonts = true;
        timeHeader.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;

        timeText = new TextField();
        timeText.text = gameTime.toString();
        interfaceLayer.addChild(timeText);
        timeText.x = 558;
        timeText.y = 0;
        timeText.selectable = false;
        timeText.embedFonts = true;
        timeText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;

        scoreHeader.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
        scoreText.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
        timeHeader.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
        timeText.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);

        var timeScorebg:Sprite = new Sprite();
        backgroundLayer.addChild(timeScorebg);
        timeScorebg.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
        timeScorebg.graphics.drawRect(0,0,600,30);
        timeScorebg.graphics.endFill();
        timeScorebg.y = 0;

        enemyShipTimer = new Timer(2000);
        enemyShipTimer.addEventListener("timer", sendEnemy);
        enemyShipTimer.start();

        enemyShipTimerMed = new Timer(2500);
        enemyShipTimerMed.addEventListener("timer", sendEnemyMed);
        enemyShipTimerMed.start();

        enemyShipTimerSmall = new Timer(2750);
        enemyShipTimerSmall.addEventListener("timer", sendEnemySmall);
        enemyShipTimerSmall.start();

        crosshair = new crosshair_mc();
        gameLayer.addChild(crosshair);

        crosshair.mouseEnabled = crosshair.mouseChildren = false;

        Mouse.hide();

        gameLayer.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCursor);
        resetScore();
    }

    function addMenuListeners():void
    {
        mainMenu.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        mainMenu.howToPlayBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showInstructions);
        mainMenu.aboutBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showAbout);
        howtoPlay.backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuReturn);
        gameEnd.playagainBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        gameAbout.backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuReturn);
    }

    function removeMenuListeners():void
    {
        mainMenu.playBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        mainMenu.howToPlayBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showInstructions);
        mainMenu.aboutBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showAbout);
        howtoPlay.backBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuReturn);
        gameEnd.playagainBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        gameAbout.backBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuReturn);
    }

    public function showInstructions(e:Event)
    {
        menuLayer.removeChild(mainMenu);
        interfaceLayer.addChild(howtoPlay);
    }

    function sendEnemy(e:Event)
    {
        var enemy = new EnemyShip();
        gameLayer.addChild(enemy);
        gameLayer.addChild(crosshair);
    }

    function sendEnemyMed(e:Event)
    {
        var enemymed = new EnemyShipMed();
        gameLayer.addChild(enemymed);
        gameLayer.addChild(crosshair);
    }

    function sendEnemySmall(e:Event)
    {
        var enemysmall = new EnemyShipSmall();
        gameLayer.addChild(enemysmall);
        gameLayer.addChild(crosshair);
    }

    static function updateScore(points)
    {
        score += points;
        scoreText.text = String(score);
        scoreHeader.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
        scoreText.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
    }

    static function resetScore()
    {
        score = 0;
        scoreText.text = String(score);
        scoreText.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
    }

    function updateTime(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        gameTime--;
        timeText.defaultTextFormat = scoreFormat;
        timeText.text = String(gameTime);
    }

    function timeExpired(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        var gameTimer:Timer = e.target as Timer;
        gameTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime)
        gameTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeExpired)

        interfaceLayer.addChild(gameEnd);

        var thisFont:Font = new myFont();
        var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        myFormat.font = thisFont.fontName;

        scoreText = new TextField();
        scoreText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
        scoreText.text = String(score);
        interfaceLayer.addChild(scoreText);
        scoreText.x = 278;
        scoreText.y = 180;
        scoreText.selectable = false;
        scoreText.embedFonts = true;
        scoreText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        scoreText.setTextFormat(gameOverscoreFormat);

        Mouse.show();
        removeChild(gameLayer);
        addMenuListeners();
    }

    function moveCursor(event:Event) 
    {
      crosshair.x=mouseX;
      crosshair.y=mouseY;
    }
    }
  }
```

I'm not quite sure how to fix this, so any advice or solution will be welcome. I can't get it to work the way I intended without getting errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is calling `menuLayer.removeChild(mainMenu);` on the second play-through is throwing the error due to the fact that you'd already removed it once already. The quickest solution would be to do a check to ensure menuLayer contains mainMenu before you try and remove it:

```
if(menuLayer contains mainMenu)
    menuLayer.removeChild(mainMenu);
```

(Note that I don't have access to the IDE right now, but I think this should work)

A more robust solution would be to call a different method when the play button is clicked from the main menu that removes `mainMenu` from `menuLayer`, then calls `startGame` (where as `playAgain` calls `startGame` directly).

**EDIT**
Ok I see what you mean. Perhaps something like this instead:

```
mainMenu.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playGame);
gameEnd.playagainBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playGameAgain);
...
public function playGame(e:Event)
{
    menuLayer.removeChild(mainMenu);
    startGame();
}
...
public function playGameAgain(e:Event)
{
    startGame();
}
...
public function startGame()
```

Comment: Hmm, I like the second idea, but not quite sure what the argument would be since `startGame()` by itself wouldn't work

Comment: @Liam the argument is null. You don't use the event, so you don't need it. Or you could pass `e`? Either way, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why your code is not working, but there is no need to fret, try:

```
 MovieClip(menuLayer.parent).removeChild(menuLayer);
```

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Main/startGame()

Comment: I still haven't got it. All I want the 'Play again' button to do is reset the game the same way it does when you close it and run it again i.e. shows the menu again and resets the score etc.

Answer (score 0):

You remove `mainMenu` in two different locations. My guess is it is being removed once and then again moments later.

```
if ( mainMenu.parent == menuLayer ) {
    menuLayer.removeChild( mainMenu );
}
```

This will verify that mainMenu is actually a child of menuLayer before removing it. You cannot remove a child from a parent that isn't actually its parent. Imagine the state taking a child away and taking custody of them from a kidnapper. It's not the prettiest comparison, but it gives the right idea.

Comment: Although this is true, it's code that essentially will just handle the problem when it occurs and allow the faulty logic that allows it to happen to live on.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot verify this without seeing how the game over is handled, but I think potentially the problem is that you are not removing your event listeners each time the game is played. Therefore when you go back to the main menu and add them again, you now have TWO listeners for playAgainBtn.

So when you end a game and click on the playAgainBtn, startGame gets called TWICE. So the first time it removes things just fine, and the second time - there's nothing to remove.  This issue will potentially exist with all of your event listeners given your current design.

If this is the case you simply need to remove your event listeners when the menu is removed.

I suggest that whenever you make the menu active you add the listeners, and then remove them whenever you hide it. Maybe have two methods, addMenuListeners and removeMenuListeners

You could create these two functions and use them where appropriate :

```
   function addMenuListeners():void
   {
        mainMenu.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        mainMenu.howToPlayBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showInstructions);
        mainMenu.aboutBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showAbout);
        howtoPlay.backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuReturn);
        gameEnd.playagainBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        gameAbout.backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuReturn);
   }

function removeMenuListeners():void
{
        mainMenu.playBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        mainMenu.howToPlayBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showInstructions);
        mainMenu.aboutBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showAbout);
        howtoPlay.backBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuReturn);
        gameEnd.playagainBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        gameAbout.backBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuReturn);
}
```

If you follow the rule of always removing the event listeners when not in use, you can avoid this issue.

Comment: Hmm, so am I right in thinking that wherever `menuLayer.addChild(mainMenu)` is used I add the listeners and when `menuLayer.removeChild(mainMenu)` is used, I remove the listeners?

Comment: I updated my question. I tried to implement your suggested solution, which is a very good idea, but my execution is probably lacking somewhere as I still get the `Supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller at Main/startGame()`

Comment: You didn't do what I said, I don't see any code that removes the event listeners.

Comment: Oops, accidentally changed the code. I've updated it now so any advice would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

if( mainMenu.parent ){ mainmenu.parent.removeChild( mainMenu  );} Or perhaps its already removed / not added at all?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
menuLayer.removeChild(mainMenu);
```

to this one..

```
if (mainMenu.parent != null && mainMenu.parent == menuLayer)
{
  menuLayer.removeChild(mainMenu);
}
```

Hope it will solve.